# Adding a html model in the script tag

Tags: html, jquery, alpine.js

I have a modal, usually it is opening with `@click="openMailSave"`, but now I need to execute it when the save is done. In my need, when I click a `<button>` it firstly executes the script and then opens the modal

The modal:

```html
<div x-show="isMailSaveOpen" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-150"
    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
    class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-end bg-black bg-opacity-50 sm:items-center sm:justify-center">
    <!-- MailSave -->
    <div x-show="isMailSaveOpen" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-150"
      x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform translate-y-1/2" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
      x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
      x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0  transform translate-y-1/2" @click.away="closeMailSave"
      @keydown.escape="closeMailSave"
      class="w-full px-6 py-4 overflow-hidden bg-white rounded-t-lg dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg sm:m-4 sm:max-w-xl"
      role="dialog" id="MailSave">
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="mt-4 mb-6">
        <!-- Modal title -->
        <p class="mb-2 text-lg font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">
          Success
        </p>
        <!-- Modal description -->

        <p class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          Mail settings have been updated successfully and the queue worker was restarted to apply these changes.
        </p>
      </div>
      <footer
        class="flex flex-col items-center justify-end px-6 py-3 -mx-6 -mb-4 space-y-4 sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-6 sm:flex-row bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">
        <button @click="closeMailSave"
          class="w-full px-5 py-3 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-150 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg dark:text-gray-400 sm:px-4 sm:py-2 sm:w-auto active:bg-transparent hover:border-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 active:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-gray">
          Ok
        </button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Execution code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testButton').on('click', saveAndTestSettings);
    $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {
      saveSettings().done(function () {
        // need to execute a modal here
      });
    });
  });
```

**Edit:**
When closing the modal, it executes

```js
closeMailSave() {
  this.isMailSaveOpen = false
  this.trapCleanup()
}
```

When using `@click="openMailSave"` it works completly fine
When using Dauros's answer, it does not define and makes an error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: closeMailSave is not defined`

Comment: Is this Alpine.js? Mixed with a bit of jQuery? You should mention that in your question, or add it to the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) from the jQuery save function that you [catch on](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on) the Alpine.js component.

```
<div x-data="{isMailSaveOpen: false}" @save-settings.document="isMailSaveOpen = true">
    <!-- Modal window -->
</div>
```

We dispatch the event on the `document` root object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {
      saveSettings().done(function () {
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('save-settings'))
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but with that, now seems alpine.js does not check the .js file for closing the modal, as an error in the web console `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: closeMailSave is not defined`, and it is defined with `this.isMailSaveOpen = false`

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add more details then? What .js file are you talking about? How do you embed it in the page? I assumed that `closeMailSave` method was properly defined somewhere since you did not included it in your question.

Comment: , added to the question

Comment: Thanks. A follow up question: what is `trapCleanup()`? Where do you define it? Furthermore, since you write `this.isMailSaveOpen = false` does it mean you have an [Alpine.js component](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data)? Because in a component we have to use `this` to access data, but in a different context it's more complicated to access Alpine.js data directly. So it's an important detail in order to answer your question correctly.

Comment: `trapCleanup()` is for making the modal be focused, it is for cleaning up the focus. And no, I'm not using Alpine.js component, heres my [alpine config](https://haste.padow.ru/hupukiqewo.js)

Comment: Hey Dauros, any updates? 

Comment: Thanks for the update. So technically `data()` is a Alpine.js component. Where did you apply it to the HTML? Because each child element should access to its methods, e.g. `closeMailSave()`. Is the `MailSave` div in your question a child element of the `data()` div? If not then you have to create a new component and put any `MailSave`-related variables and methods there and apply it to a the MailSave's div, e.g. `<div x-data="MailSaveComponent()">...</div>`. (Or you can also move the `MailSave` div so it becomes a chlld element of `data()` component.)

Comment: I may not understand the questions, `data()` is assigned in the
`<html :class="{ 'dark': dark }" x-data="data()" lang="en">`,  `MailSave` id is in the show modal (not sure how do I say it, but here how it [looks](https://haste.padow.ru/mayoralihi.html))

Comment: Hey, any update Dauros?

Comment: I've got it, instead of using `@click="closeMailSave"`, I will use `@click="isMailSaveOpen = false " @click="trapCleanup()"`